How to use 5.1 speakers with a laptop/docking station?
I bought a speaker system with 5 speakers and a subwoofer.
The green plug from the speakers is plugged into the green port on the docking station, but the 2 rear speakers are not being fed input.
Do I need to buy an adapter of some kind, to ensure all 5 speakers work?
Help appreciated.

The standard PC audio adapter (aka sound "card") is only capable of stereo (2 channel) audio. Does your laptop advertise any capability of decoding a Dolby or DTS codec and outputting 6 channels of audio? It's not likely since you neglect to mention the appropriate 3.5mm jacks (typically colored green, orange, and black).
